# Can we synchronise or link tabs in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I was wondering if there is a way to synchronise or link tabsets of an Rmarkdown document knitted to html?

In the document below, when I click the 'Dataset B' under the 'Analysis 1' header, I'd like the the 'Dataset B' tab under 'Analysis 2' header to become active / open as well.

```
---
title: "My Document"
output: html_document
---

# Analysis 1 {.tabset}

## Dataset A

Analysis 1 data A results

## Dataset B

Analysis 1 data B results

# Analysis 2 {.tabset}

## Dataset A

Analysis 2 data A results

## Dataset B

Analysis 2 data B results
```